# AsynchronousFileChannel - make sure that close() happens after writes are finished

Tags: java, nio, nio2

I have gzip compressor which for the purpose of this question can be seen as a simple buffer.

The compressor writes into a NIO2 `AsynchronousFileChannel`. Once there are enough compressed bytes, the buffer is flushed and an async `AsynchronousFileChannel.write()` call is initiated.

Once **all** writes are complete, the compressor might still contain data. So I need to:

- flush & close the compressor
- perform one last write
- close the `AsynchronousFileChannel` itself.

The documentation for `AsynchronousFileChannel.close()` states that

> Any outstanding asynchronous operations upon this channel will
>   complete with the exception AsynchronousCloseException

Might this include the last write submitted by the same thread just before it calls `close()`?

In other words, is the following safe?

```
AsynchronousFileChannel channel = ...
...
//Is there a chance that this write will throw an AsynchronousCloseException?
channel.write(...); 
channel.close();
```

or do I need to block until the last write returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Might this include the last write submitted by the same thread just before it calls close()?

Yes, of course.

> In other words, is the following safe?

No.

> or do I need to block until the last write returns?

You need to do the close in the completion handler for the last write, or after you have successfully obtained its `Future`.

Comment: I suspect that you're right, but is this written explicitly anywhere?

Comment: Part of it is written in the quotation you provided, and the other part is implicit in the notion of asynchronicity.

Comment: You're right about the quotation, but the case in question is one in which the thread calling `write` is the same as the one calling `close`. I agree that in the general case, with two different threads that the answer is obvious. But since there's only one thread, and the call to `write()` completes strictly before `close()` then perhaps the `write` is no longer "outstanding". It's a long shot, but I was just wondering whether there was something more explicit written about it.

Comment: Once the `write()` has started, it is asynchronous. *Ergo* the case where the thread calling `write()` is the same as the thread calling `close()` is covered completely by your quotation.